# Как изменить имя вкладки

Tags: c#, winforms

При двойном щелчке мыши по вкладке нужно вывести поле типа Textbox прямо на названии вкладки и чтоб его название можно было сменить. Как это сделать. Код не нужен, нужна идея.Использую WinForms

Comment: Что используете? WinForms, WPF?

Comment: @Donil Ответил.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно сменить название вкладки, то его и меняйте, зачем изобретать велосипед?

```
private void tabControl1_Selected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e)
{
    e.TabPage.Text = "New Name";
}
```

Если всё-таки зачем-то нужен `TextBox`, создавайте его динамически:

```
private void tabControl1_Selected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = new TextBox();
    textBox.Location = e.TabPage.Parent.Location;
    textBox.Parent = this;
    textBox.BringToFront();
    textBox.Text = "Some text";
}
```

Проблема в том, что на `TabControl` можно добавить только `TabPage`. Поэтому родителем текстбокса делаем форму.
На саму вкладку можно добавить `TextBox`, но только на рабочую поверхность, не на заголовок.

Что с ним делать дальше - вам решать...